# Qual a diferença entre referenciar um atributo diretamente ou por get/set?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, atributos, getters-setters

Como exemplo tenho um `private String atributo`, logo posso ter dois jeitos de referenciar o mesmo, isso internamente na classe:

```
this.atributo
```

E também:

```
this.getAtributo();
```

É correto dizer que é errado usar `this.atributo` e certo usar `this.getAtributo()`?

Em casos, não preciso pegar ou *setar* valores da classe na meu `main()` ou em outra classe, então nem crio os *getters* e *setters*, pois criar é uma forma indireta de tornar um atributo privado em atributo público, logo seria falho para segurança.

Mas voltado a questão principal, é errado usar `this.atributo`? E qual a diferença entre usar um ou outro?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não há falha de segurança alguma permitir o acesso aos campos ([não gosto do termo atributo para isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101), ainda mais neste contexto). No máximo é uma quebra de encapsulamento, ou [vazamento de abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101), mesmo assim depende do caso.

Se só tem o campo privado, tudo normal, nenhum problema, pode fazer à vontade. O problema começa ficar mais complicado quando tem ambos.

De fato nada impede que acesse um ou outro conforme a necessidade. Obviamente que o acesso direto ao campo só permite pegar o valor e alterar seu valor. Os métodos *getter/setter* podem dar a impressão que é um acesso comum, mas eles podem estar realizando outras ações no momento do acesso ou atribuição. Então eles só são equivalentes por coincidência, seus propósitos são diferentes.

O ideal é acessar pelos métodos (quando eles existem) para manter a coerência. Mas se tiver um bom motivo para acessar o campo e souber da implicação que o acesso direto não executará as ações normalmente estabelecidas nos métodos, tá tudo ok.

Aí a resposta é: depende. O mais importante é entender que a chamada de um ou outro potencialmente possui semântica bem diferente. Isto pode ser bem confuso.

Os métodos costumam ser mais lentos, mas quando são acessados privadamente há uma otimização e provavelmente a chamada do método será substituída pelo código dele ([*inline expansion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion)), se a implementação for simples.

Como curiosidade, os métodos são criados por padrão pelos programadores, mesmo que a única ação deles seja o acesso e atribuição direta sem fazer mais nada, ou seja, faz o mesmo que se estivesse acessando o campo direto, porque se um dia precisar dos métodos eles já estavam sendo usados. Se começar tornando o campo público e um dia precisar adicionar um processamento no seu acesso de leitura ou escrita, aí o método terá que ser adicionado, mudando a API pública e exigindo que todos os códigos consumidores dela sejam alterados. Criando uma abstração aumenta o encapsulamento e melhora o desacoplamento escondendo os detalhes de implementação.

Então, se o código só terá acesso ao campo privativamente OU você tem certeza absoluta que nunca terá um método para acessar aquele campo, pode expor o campo. Se não puder garantir isso é mais seguro criar os métodos. A não ser que a API não seja tão pública e aceite ficar alterado códigos consumidores.

Qual é o melhor depende de cada cenário. O que não pode é pregar o desacoplamento e expor o detalhe de implementação, que é o campo. Ou terá um benefício ou o outro, tudo é *tradeoff*.

Respondi [algo semelhante sobre C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Acabei "voando" aqui na hora da pergunta e coloquei parâmetro ao invés de atributos. Então, a ausência dos getters e setters e referência direta ao atributo seria indicada quando o desenvolvedor tem certeza que o atributo não vai sofrer alteração relativa a sua validação e não será exposto para outra classe?

Comment: Se trocar o E que você usou aí por um OU, é isso mesmo. Obviamente que se o campo é só detalhes de implementação (é privado) não há problema algum e não tem porque criar os métodos. Tem gente que cria neste cenário porque todo mundo cria, não tem um motivo real. É recomendado que não se crie neste caso. Outra situação agora: se vai expor o campo, considere que nunca mais vai poder torná-lo privado se um dia precisar. Porque alguém pode ter consumido o campo direto, uma mudança seria uma quebra da API. Em classes anêmicas fazem sentido. Em outras tem que tomar cuidado.

Comment: Particularmente eu prefiro evitar criar os métodos, até que sejam necessários. Mas é um erro adotar isto como padrão. Tem que realmente analisar caso a caso. Porque um erro aí pode criar enormes complicadores. Se eu estiver desenvolvendo sozinho ou em um equipe enxuta, coesa, com boas ferramentas de *refactoring*, eu arriscaria mais não usar a abstração e exporia mais o campo. Em uma API para terceiros consumir, eu iria pelo caminho seguro com certeza e criaria as abstrações. Caso contrário uma mudança forçaria deprecar esta API e criar uma nova.

Answer (score 5):

Antes de qualquer coisa, você falou em segurança. Segurança não é a intenção de escolher usar variáveis privadas. A intenção é proteger-se contra vícios de programação (especialmente o acoplamento) que levam a uma degradação da qualidade do código.

Dito isso, não é uma prática boa ou ruim usar `getVariavel` em vez de `this.variavel` dentro da própria classe porque é perfeitamente normal (até desejável) que os métodos da classe manipulem (de forma racional, claro) os campos dela. O(a) autor(a) da classe entende aquelas variáveis e o importante, no final das contas, é que os métodos honrem a interface pública da classe e as garantias propostas por ela (ou pré/pós condições).

Há quem vá falar em preocupação com desempenho, mas isso é paranoia-- é muito fácil para o compilador remover essa chamada extra ou durante a compilação para bytecode ou durante a execução mesmo. E, naturalmente, preocupação com desempenho sem medições é otimização prematura, famosa por ser a origem de todos os males.

Comment: A questão de segurança que falei é no caso quando não uso get e set fora da classe, então na minha visão é mais viável não gerar get e set asim já eliminando a possibilidade de acessa-la fora da classe, ja que para o funcionamento não foi necessário compartilhar com getter e setter

Comment: Um dos maiores erros do ensino de programação orientada a objetos que eu vejo sendo cometidos é que você tem criar get/set pra todas as suas variáveis logo de cara. Isso simplesmente não é verdade. Criar variáveis privadas e depois get/sets públicos é quase tão ruim quanto deixar tudo público. Crie setters apenas quando necessário-- de preferência, não crie setters: crie métodos que alteram o estado interno da classe de uma forma controlada. Por exemplo: crie um método `acelerar` e não um `setVelocidade` (e isso só quando surgir a necessidade).

Answer (score 2):

O atributo *private* não deixa você acessar a variável ou método em outra classe, a não ser na própria classe, utilizando a palavra reservada *this*.

---

Quando você precisar acessar em outra classe, você precisa usar um *get* e *set*.

---

Então usar *this.getParametro()* na class que contém a variável privada não faz muito sentido porque seria mais fácil usar o *this*.

---

Como você disse, se você não precisa acessar, então nem precisa criar os métodos *get* e *set*.

---

Respondendo sua pergunta final: Não, não seria errado usar *this.parametro*, na verdade é o jeito certo. Espero ter esclarecido sua dúvida.

Answer (score 0):

Com os setters, você pode checar por condicoes antes de efetivamente alterar a variavel.

```
public setIdade(int anos) {
    if (anos > 0) {
      idade = anos;
    }
}
```

Afinal, uma idade não deveria poder ser negativa, embora um int possa.

Utilizando o atributo diretamente, não há como verificar a semantica da alteração. Isto é, faz sentido uma idade negativa?

No caso dos getters, é voce poder mudar implementacao sem alterar a abstracao. No exemplo, deixar de utilizar um inteiro para guardar a idade e passar a usar as datas atual e de nascimento.

O codigo dos clientes da classe não precisará saber desta mudança. Basta chamar getIdade() como já faz atualmente.

```
public int getIdade() {
  return this.idade;
}

public int getIdade() {
  return diferenca(hoje, nascimento);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Uma boa analogia para esse problema é a clássica de abrir a televisão para trocar o canal (variáveis privadas) no lugar de usar o controle remoto (métodos).

Imagine que você tem uma classe televisão. E você quer mudar o canal.

Pode ser mais fácil acessar a variável canal diretamente (abrindo a televisão), mas você quer manter a lógica de trocar o canal sob responsabilidade da televisão.

Então, o ideal, é criar um método subirCanal() e descerCanal() e/ou mudarCanal() também porque você mantem a televisão fazendo o controle do canal e tudo o que pode ser necessário checar ao fazer esse tipo de alteração.

Fazendo alterações diretamente a variável da televisão, você pode fazer o software funcionar agora, mas é muito mais fácil de a lógica quebrar em uma manutenção futura.