# O que acontece na vida real em um ambiente de desenvolvedores se o programador não encapsular um atributo?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software, encapsulamento, getters-setters, private

O programador João foi lá e criou uma classe `Cliente` e o atributo `public double saldo` e o método `Sacar()` publico também.

Qual o problema em deixar o atributo `double saldo`, afinal qual o problema poderia ocorrer se o João não privar o atributo saldo?

Eu só consigo imaginar que alguém poderia escolher algum cliente aleatório e aumentar o saldo de uma pessoa e vocês?

```
class Cliente 
{    
    public decimal saldo;
    public void Sacar()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Se "alguém" for uma outra classe da aplicação, é isso mesmo.

Comment: Já tem uma resposta no site sobre encapsulamentos! só não consegui achar

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15467/m%C3%A9todos-e-propriedades-em-c-vantagens-e-desvantagens @bfavaretto ou essa, imagine você já tem algumas !!! ;)

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Há um terremoto no Canadá :)

Se for necessário e souber o que está fazendo não tem problema. É claro que este exemplo pode ser um problema porque um saldo não deveria ser manipulado diretamente. Não sei nem se um cliente deveria ter um saldo e um método `Sacar()`. Eu sei que pode ser só um exemplo, mas ele induz a algo errado.

Mas não pense que ele dá alguma segurança. Se um programador quiser mudar um valor ele vai mudar. O encapsulamento só protege do programador bem intencionado que não quer correr o risco de cometer um erro acessando o campo de forma direta. É algo que o compilador "impede" o acesso, mas daí pra frente tudo pode acontecer.

É mais uma questão de organização do código, algo que ajuda gerenciar a complexidade dos objetos e passar a intenção correta. [Tem a ver com encapsulamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129353/101).

Desta forma ajuda a [obter a coesão e evita o acoplamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96656/101) não intencional.

Na verdade tem um problema pior nesse código que é armazenar [valor monetário em um `double`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40045/101).

[Não sou fã do termo atributo para isto, prefiro campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Veja mais:

- [Por que não devo alterar os "getter"s e "setter"s?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/134750/101).
- [Getters e Setters são obrigatórios ou facilitadores?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33723/101)
- [Getters e setters são uma ilusão do encapsulamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25995/101)

Comment: No caso de uma equipe de desenvolvedores trabalhando no mesmo projeto o Private é para assegurar que nenhum outro desenvolvedor mexa no seu codigo por isso o uso do Private entendi certo ?

Comment: Não é exatamente o oposto disto, é para que uma outra parte do código não possa acessar esse atributo diretamente. Mais nada. O programador faz o que ele quiser no código. Até quem não é o programador da aplicação faz o que quiser se tiver acesso ao executável. Como eu disse na resposta não é um mecanismo de segurança, é só organização.

Comment: Entendi, graças a sua explicação consegui entender que o encapsulamento anda de mãos dadas com o Principio da Responsabilidade Unica.

Comment: @user3671786 não, isso não acontece, pelo menos não diretamente.